# Transformer design for SMPS

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply

This is my first time making SMPS for my application, so parden my silly mistakes and questions if any.

I stay in India where 230V ac rms @ 50Hz is available. I took 210V as min and 250V as max input. I need to get 5V@2A as output and using TNY266 as offline switcher for SMPS regulation. I referred following 2 links for making my first design:
http://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/2-8.pdf

https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/AN/AN-4137.pdf

I calculated all the values which I attached in excel sheet.
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhoWru2BCG9EgoRuFUzRit8UTTyGbg

It seems I need to wind transformer myself. So, I calculated primary and secondary turns used the table given in below link:
http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm

So, primary is 144 turns of AWG 27 wire based on switching frequency and current and secondary is 4 turns of AWG 15 based on current but the switching frequency of that AWG is very low compared to the switching frequency of TNY266 i.e. 132 kHz. Did I select the correct AWG of wire for primary and secondary? And as per Infineon-Mouser design guide, I have decided to use EE16/8/5 core, is this the correct selection?

Am I doing correct calculations? If not, what are the corrections? Any recommended readings on subject to help design power supply and transformer design?

Thanks

Ashutosh

Comment: From what I have heard of indias power quality, 210-250V seems to be a bit narrow...

Comment: Explain to me why you would NOT buy an off-the-shelf solution for this. Because that 1) will be cheaper 2) have a guaranteed safety level (proper mains isolation) 3) save you **loads of time** 4) save you cost because the first design will not be good, you will need to redesign. Designing mains supplies is better left to experienced specialists, even many experienced engineers just an the off-the-shelf module because it saves so much hassle. You need 5 V, 2 A, there is plenty of choice with that output, I bet I have more than 5 of those in my drawer.

Comment: @PlasmaHH It depends on where exactly you stay in India. Where I live; we get stable 230Vrms with almost no fluctuations.

Comment: I have to agree with @FakeMoustache.  This is not something you do as a novice.  If you don't understand creepage and clearance distances, winding isolation, EMI filter design, safety concerns like capacitor discharge, etc. you should not be trying this.  Try a low voltage DC-DC converter if you're looking for a learning experience, leave the offline stuff to the pros.

Comment: I am making my own supply because, I need to integrate this supply on the same board of my application having microcontroller and other peripherals. And at some point we all learn to make some stuff or start somewhere for new things. It is very difficult not impossible. And if gurus are willing to share experiences, it would be great. I also have tried to get some designs from google, but not much info on BOM has given, it is like take this module and use it; which I do not prefer.